# Creating a variable stored procedure to be used in SSRS

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am trying to create a stored procedure that references variable input from SSRS.  Here is the code for the complex query.  I am using CTE's to make the code more readable.

```
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[adm_AuditHospMonth]    Script Date: 11/25/2013 9:39:10 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Scott Schmeling
-- Create date: 11/25/2013
-- Description: Determines the products in which the price was lowered and revenue lost during a set time period.
-- =============================================
*/


Create Procedure dbo.PriceErosion
    @StartDate as Date
    ,@EndDate as Date
    ,@CurDate as Date
    ,@Hospital as Int
    ,@Division as Int

as

/*
Test Data

Declare @StartDate as Date
Declare @EndDate as Date
Declare @Hospital as Int
Declare @Division as Int
DECLARE @curDate Date   

SET @curDate = GETDATE() 
Set @StartDate = CASE WHEN @StartDate IS NULL THEN DATEADD(dd, -31, Dateadd(dd, -1, @curdate) ) ELSE @StartDate END
Set @EndDate = CASE WHEN @EndDate IS NULL THEN Dateadd(dd, -1, @curdate) ELSE @EndDate END 
Set @Hospital = 3;
*/ 

Begin

    --  Sets the Baseline Price Date in the PriceChangeHistory Table.
    With PC1
    as
        (Select
            HospitalMasterID
            ,TxnCode
            ,UserInfoMasterID
            ,Active
            ,min(TxnDateTime) as StartingDate
        From
        PriceChangeHistory
        Where
        TxnDateTime Between @StartDate and @EndDate
        Group By
            HospitalMasterID, TxnCode, UserInfoMasterID, Active)

    -- Gets the Baseline Price for the period from the PriceChangeHistory Table
    ,PC
    as
        (Select
            PC1.HospitalMasterID
            ,PC1.TxnCode
            ,PC1.UserInfoMasterID
            ,PC1.Active
            ,Cast (PC1.StartingDate as Date) as StartingDate
            ,PC2.OldPrice as StartingPrice
            ,PC2.NewPrice
            ,PC2.TxnSubType
        From
        PC1
        Inner Join
        PriceChangeHistory as PC2
        On
        PC1.HospitalMasterID = PC2.HospitalMasterID
        and
        PC1.TxnCode = PC2.TxnCode
        and
        PC1.StartingDate = PC2.TxnDateTime
        Where
        PC2.OldPrice > PC2.NewPrice)

    --MedicalHistory Information
    ,MH
    as
        (Select
            HospitalMasterID
            ,PatientID
            ,TxnDate
            ,TxnCode
            ,Description
            ,ListAmount
            ,ExtendedAmount
            ,TxnType
            ,Quantity
            ,(Case
                When Quantity <> '1' Then (ListAmount/Quantity)
                Else ListAmount
                End) as UnitPrice
        From
            MedicalHistory
        Where
            TxnDate Between @StartDate and @EndDate
            and
            _IsServOrITem = 1)

    -- Determines the Revenue lost per each sale, also reduces the results to only those items where the Price was lowered not raised.
    ,RL
    as
        (Select
            PC.HospitalMasterID
            ,MH.PatientID
            ,PC.TxnCode
            ,PC.TxnSubType
            ,MH.Description
            ,PC.UserInfoMasterID as ChangedByUserID
            ,MH.TxnDate
            ,PC.StartingPrice
            ,Cast (MH.UnitPrice as Money) as UnitPrice
            ,Cast ((StartingPrice - UnitPrice) as Money) as RevenueLost
        From 
        PC
        Left OUter Join
        MH
        on
        PC.HospitalMasterID = MH.HospitalMasterID
        and
        PC.TxnCode = MH.TxnCode
        Where
        PC.StartingPrice > MH.UnitPrice)

    --- Determine the name of the tech changing the prices.
    ,UI
    as
        (Select
            HospitalMasterID
            ,UserInfoMasterID
            ,Name
        From
            UserInfo)

    --- Get the Division and Hospital Name for each Hospital.

    ,HODI
    as
        (Select
            DI.DivisionID
            ,DI.DivisionName
            ,HO.HospMastID
            ,HO.HospCode
            ,HO.HospName
        From
            ref_Hospital as HO
            inner Join
            ref_Division as DI
            on
            HO.DivisionID = DI.DivisionID)

    ,HI
    as
        (Select
            HODI.DivisionID
            ,HODI.DivisionName
            ,RL.HospitalMasterID
            ,HODI.HospCode
            ,HODI.HospName
            ,RL.PatientID
            ,RL.TxnCode
            ,RL.TxnSubType
            ,RL.Description
            ,RL.ChangedByUserID
            ,RL.TxnDate
            ,RL.StartingPrice
            ,RL.UnitPrice
            ,RL.RevenueLost
        From
            RL
            Left Outer Join
            HODI
            ON
            RL.HospitalMasterID = HODI.HospMastID
            Where
            RL.HospitalMasterID = @Hospital
            and
            RL.DivisionID = @Division
            and
            TXNDate Between @StartDate and @EndDate)

Select
*
From
HI

End
```

Every time I try to run this stored procedure through SSRS, I get an error stating that the variables are not defined.  I am sure there is something I am doing incorrectly in the SP mode because the query works fine with the Test Data and by itself.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Have you set the commands in the dataset? Is the datasource accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS should be able to detect what parameters your sproc needs and add them in automatically. It unfortunatly isn't clever enough to work out datatypes, so you will have to manually select these.

Select a new dataset and choose sproc. Make. sure that you select the fully qualified name. Then click the refresh fields button.

[image: Sproc]

If you check the Parameters tab of the dataset you should see that your parameters have been added, if not then you can manually add them. Remember that parameter names are case-sensitive.

[image: Sproc2]

Finally, you'll have to go into each parameter properties and manually select the correct datatype as SSRS will default it to text. Just double click on the parameter in the report data on the left of the screen.

[image: Sproc1]

NB. You don't seem to use CurDate anywhere in your sproc so you may as well remove it.

Comment: Thanks, it works well.  CurDate is used in the Case StartDate and Case EndDate are Null.  This may not be the best way to do it.  If there is a better one I will be glad to use it.

Comment: @SASUSMC there is no need to pass it into the sproc as you are setting the value in the sproc using GETDATE(). Also you can use the sql [`ISNULL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function rather than CASE WHEN.